# "Ob wir das (wohl) schaffen?" - Ist eine deliberative Frage ein Haupt- oder Nebensatz?

Tags: grammar-identification

Wir kennen den Verbzweitnebensatz, welcher bei der Redewiedergabe genutzt wird.

Bei der deliberative Frage begegnet uns dann aber gewissermaßen das umgekehrte Beispiel: "Ob der Himmel blau ist?". "Was er wohl dieses Jahr macht?".
(Duden 4 S.890)
Aufgeführt wird es im Dudenband 4 allerdings unter Fragesätzen, wo es eigentlich um Hauptsätze geht. Ein Nebensatz müsste aber **untergeordnet** sein, was der Deliberativsatz nicht ist - Er steht allein.

Der Duden gibt auch noch den "Echofragesatz" an, zu diesem sagt er explizit, dass eine Ellipse vorliegt, er also untergeordnet ist; tatsächlich ein Nebensatz ist.
Zum **deliberativen Fragesatz wird das aber nicht gesagt**.  Es wird nicht die "Erweiterungsprobe" angesprochen, wie man es vermuten könnte: "Ich frage mich, ob...".
Denn die Intonation entspricht nicht der des Nebensatzes.

Besonders in Bezug auf den "Ob"-Satz muss man dann aber bemerken, dass "ob" eine Subjunktion ist, und Subjunktionen nur mit Nebensätzen verwendet werden.
Unter den Modus/Satz-Typen ist das kein Einzelfall; Dem Exklamativsatz ordnet man Sätze wie "Und **ob** ich kommen werde!" zu.

Hier sprechen also verschiedene Dinge für mich gegeneinander: Nicht alleinstehend aber mit Subjunktion, Intonation eines Hauptsatzes aber Form eines Nebensatzes mit Verb in letzter Position.

Deshalb stellt sich mir die Frage - Was denn nun? Was ist es?
Kann ein Hauptsatz in Funktion also ein Nebensatz in Form sein?
Es gibt Partizipien, Infinitive, usw, welche alle hauptsatzwertig sind.
Wieso dann nicht vielleicht auch ein Satz, der wie ein Nebensatz aussieht?

Comment: Die meisten Grammatiken bezeichnen solche Sätze als "selbstständige Sätze mit Verbendstellung" und halten sich aus der Diskussion, ob das dann ein Haupt- oder Nebensatz ist, vollkommen heraus. Ich glaube, der Versuch der Einordnung solcher Sätze, die zwar idiomatisch, aber nicht grammatikalisch zweifelsfrei sind, ist ein bisschen hoffnungslos. Manchmal muss man einfach auch ein Auge zudrücken können.

Comment: @tofro Danke. Es scheint also eine Art Ausnahme zu sein.

Comment: @tofro Hätten Sie (oder jemand, der das liest) eine konkrete Quelle? Im Duden 4 habe ich bereits geschaut, wie in der Antwort steht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deutschlerner, die noch kein C2-Level erreicht haben, sollten hier erstmal weghören - Ein großer Teil ihres mühsam erkämpften Grammatikgebäudes könnte einstürzen...**

Wir haben alle gelernt, dass ein ordentlicher deutscher Satz in Hauptsätzen V2-Stellung, in Nebensätzen Verbletztstellung fordert (Fragesätze dürfen davon abweichen, da gibt es auch Verberststellung). Das ist so ziemlich die generellste Regel, die man kennen muss, um die Flexibilität der Reihenfolge der Satzglieder im Deutschen in den Griff zu bekommen.

Und doch gibt es Ausnahmen davon:

*Ausnahmen von dieser Regel stellen die uneingeleiteten Nebensätze und die selbständigen Sätze mit Verbendstellung dar.* [(1)](http://oehl.gesus-info.de/CV/Kurse/JWG-Uni_Ffm/13_SoSe/PS_GrammAnalyse/03b_GrammAn-BlockIII_Komplexe-Saetze.pdf) [(2)](https://www.leibniz-zas.de/fileadmin/Archiv2019/mitarbeiter/truckenbrodt/VL-Saetze.pdf) (weitere Verweise siehe dort)

Zu den "selbstständigen Sätzen mit Verbendstellung" (man beachte, dass sich diese Terminologie absichtlich darum drückt, zu bestimmen, ob es sich um Haupt- oder Nebensätze handelt, denn wahrscheinlich weder noch) kann man folgende Beispiele konstruieren:

> Ob er wohl kommt?

(Selbstständiger Verbend-Fragesatz)

> Was der alles gelesen hat!

(Exklamativsatz)

> Wenn sie nur schon heute kämen!

(Optativsatz)

> Bitte nicht aus dem Fenster lehnen!

(Infinitivischer Begehrsatz)

> Und ob er heute noch kommt!

Alle diese Sätze sind selbstständige Sätze (es ist ja sonst nichts dran), haben aber Verbendstellung wie ein Nebensatz.

Bei manchen der Beispiele könnte man sich eine Ellipse vostellen (also einen Hauptsatz, der der Einfachheit halber weggelassen wurde), bei vielen solcher Sätze kann man das aber nicht. Die (vor allem neuere) Literatur lehnt i.A. eine Rückführung auf eine Ellipse (die man nur annehmen würde, um die "fundamentale Grundregel" V2-Stellung zu schützen), ab und akzeptiert ganz einfach, dass solche selbstständigen Sätze (und damit Ausnahmen von V2) vorkommen und grammatisch sind. Es sind ganz einfach selbstständige Sätze mit der Syntax von Nebensätzen.